# custom instances of onepage checkout, possible in magento?

Tags: php, xml, magento

what im trying to do is setup 3 different instances of the onepage checkout process, and i figured the easiest way to go about that was to create 3 new cms pages, override the xml with the following (taken from checkout.xml, see bottom of post for code) and have that work.

this loads all the content fine but when going through the steps as a guest it triggers some failure redirect (located in onepage.phtml i believe), and it looks like it doesnt understand what /checkout/onepage/saveMethod is (returns 403 error in browser), im assuming because im really in some instance of the cms page and not a checkout page, as in certain things are not being loaded behind the scenes.

i was hoping to use this method to customize this process as i felt it looked like the cleanest way to go about it without having to change too much, but im not really sure what exactly is not being loaded here to make this work and how to load it. i was trying to find a way to call mage_checkout something or other via xml to get the cms page to recognize it as checkout and have it work, but couldnt find anything.

if theres an easier way to do this, my end goal really is to have 3 separate sets of /template/checkout/onepage/ phtml templates to work with, as theyre all going to be different, attached to 3 different urls (and i was going to just hide the default /onepage/ checkout).

```
    <!-- Mage_Checkout -->
    <remove name="left"/>

    <reference name="root">
        <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/2columns-right.phtml</template></action>
    </reference>
    <reference name="right">
        <action method="unsetChildren"></action>

        <block type="checkout/onepage_progress" name="checkout.progress" before="-" template="checkout/onepage/progress.phtml"/>
        <block type="livechat/template" before="checkout.progress" name="livechat.chat" template="livechat/chat.phtml"/>
    </reference>
    <reference name="content">
        <block type="checkout/onepage" name="checkout.onepage" template="checkout/onepage.phtml">
            <block type="checkout/onepage_login" name="checkout.onepage.login" as="login" template="checkout/onepage/login.phtml"/>
            <block type="checkout/onepage_billing" name="checkout.onepage.billing" as="billing" template="checkout/onepage/billing.phtml"/>
            <block type="checkout/onepage_shipping" name="checkout.onepage.shipping" as="shipping" template="checkout/onepage/shipping.phtml"/>
            <block type="checkout/onepage_shipping_method" name="checkout.onepage.shipping_method" as="shipping_method" template="checkout/onepage/shipping_method.phtml">
                <block type="checkout/onepage_shipping_method_available" name="checkout.onepage.shipping_method.available" as="available" template="checkout/onepage/shipping_method/available.phtml"/>
                <block type="checkout/onepage_shipping_method_additional" name="checkout.onepage.shipping_method.additional" as="additional" template="checkout/onepage/shipping_method/additional.phtml"/>
            </block>
            <block type="checkout/onepage_payment" name="checkout.onepage.payment" as="payment" template="checkout/onepage/payment.phtml">
                <block type="checkout/onepage_payment_methods" name="checkout.payment.methods" as="methods" template="checkout/onepage/payment/methods.phtml">
                    <action method="setMethodFormTemplate"><method>purchaseorder</method><template>payment/form/purchaseorder.phtml</template></action>
                </block>
            </block>
            <block type="checkout/onepage_review" name="checkout.onepage.review" as="review" template="checkout/onepage/review.phtml">
                <block type="checkout/agreements" name="checkout.onepage.agreements" as="agreements" template="checkout/onepage/agreements.phtml"/>
            </block>
        </block>
    </reference>
```

Comment: please explain what is the point of all that so we could actually understand the question

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is to set up three sites or stores in your admin area. You then just have to set up a theme for each one as per the documentation. You can modify each theme/view individually as required.